# Failed to create BuildConfig class-Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I updated the SDK to SDK-18 and ADT to 22 version my current project shows
**FAILED TO CREATE BUILDCONFIG CLASS**  Im working as normal user.
If i open the same workspace as administrator it works good.
i tried
`projcet->clean
android tools->fix project setup
Window->preference->Java->build path->changed folders to project`
I tried to create new workspace and import the same project got same problem
Help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by delete the file under bin/ and gen/ directory. I think it is the permission problem. Check your project directory and make sure you have admin right.

Answer (score 0):

After I imported the sample project from CD. I got the same error message. It is a permission problem. I did the following steps:

1. close project in ADT
2. change the  directory and subdirectory permission in workspace.

Then, the error message gone.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps

1. Delete the bin folder
2. Restart eclipse
3. Clean and run the project

Answer (score 0):

Chanage Permission of your project directory to 777. Because of read only permission eclipse not able to write new files in bin folder.